# jQuery code repeating problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a piece of code in jQuery that I use to get the contents of an iFrame after you click a link and once the content is completed loading. It works, but I have a problem with it repeating - at least I think that is what it is doing, but I can't figure out why or how.

jQuery JS:

```
 $(".pageSaveButton").bind("click",function(){
   var theID = $(this).attr("rel");
   $("#fileuploadframe").load(function(){
     var response = $("#fileuploadframe").contents().find("html").html();
     $.post("siteCreator.script.php",
        {action:"savePage",html:response, id: theID},
         function(data){
           alert(data);
         });
   });
 });
```

HTML Links ( one of many ):

```
<a href="templates/1000/files/index.php?pg=0&preview=false" 
       target="fileuploadframe" class="pageSaveButton" rel="0">Home</a>
```

So when you click the link, the page that is linked to is opened into the iframe, then the JS fires and waits for the content to finish loading and then grabs the iframe's content and sends it to a PHP script to save to a file. I have a problem where when you click multiple links in a row to save multiple files, the content of all the previous files are overwritten with the current file you have clicked on. I have checked my PHP and am pretty positive the fault is with the JS.

I have noticed that - since I have the PHP's return value alerted - that I get multiple alert boxes. If it is the first link you have clicked on since the main page loaded - then it is fine, but when you click on a second link you get the alert for each of the previous pages you clicked on in addition to the expected alert for the current page.

I hope I have explained well, please let me know if I need to explain better - I really need help resolving this. :) (and if you think the php script is relevant, I can post it - but it only prints out the $_POST variables to let me know what page info is being sent for debugging purposes.)

Thanks ahead of time,
Key

Comment: Just an aside, - why not use PHP's cURL library, if it's available? http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: @Jared: I did not think to...if you think it would be better I may look into it as an improvement after I get it working right this way first.

Comment: @Jared: Adding to previous comment: I actually did try to implement this with cURL, but I forget why I stopped it - I think it had something to do with me not being able to figure out passing the variables through the URL, I don't think I could get it to work right.

Comment: For some cases, I'm sure it's not the best solution (for instance, if you need to be logged in). It just seemed as if there may be a round trip occurring that may not have to. Just a thought.

Comment: You actually do need to be logged into the system to be able to use the interface - but it has nothing to do with the rest of the application - except for the initial access given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From jQuery `.load()` [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) I think you need to change your script to:

```
$(".pageSaveButton").bind("click",function(){
    var theID = $(this).attr("rel");
    var lnk = $(this).attr("href");//LINK TO LOAD
    $("#fileuploadframe").load(lnk,
        function(){ 
        //EXECUTE AFTER LOAD IS COMPLETE
            var response = $("#fileuploadframe").contents().find("html").html();
            $.post("siteCreator.script.php",
                {
                    action:"savePage",
                    html:response, 
                    id: theID
                },
                function(data){alert(data);}
            );
    });
});
```

As for the multiple responses, you can use something like [blockui](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/) to disable any further clicks till the `.post` call returns.

Comment: I agree - this looks like your callback is in the wrong place.

Comment: This fixed the problem! That sure was a simple fix. As for the blockui, I actually have that implemented for another section of my site - but the problem with multiple links was not that they were all being clicked at once before the post was completed, but the block ui is still a good suggestion to stop user input.

Comment: Now I have the problem of the content being grabbed before the link could be loaded into the iframe, so if you have not clicked a link yet - it gets a blank html page, but if you have - it gets the content of the previous link you clicked on - not the current page. I thought the function part of load was only supposed to execute after the iframe loaded. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the line

```
$("#fileuploadframe").load(function(){
```

Gets executed every time you press a link. Only add the loadhandler to the iframe on document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

If a user has the ability via your UI to click multiple links that trigger this function, then you are going to run into this problem no matter what since you use the single iframe.  I would suggest creating an iframe per save process, that why the rendering of one will not affect the other.